# quotas are exceeded error while deploying Vertex AI Matching Engine Index

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am following this example [notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/community/matching_engine/matching_engine_for_indexing.ipynb) and used custom word embeddings of my own.

i am getting the following error while deploying the index at this step

```
r = index_endpoint_client.deploy_index(
    index_endpoint=INDEX_ENDPOINT_NAME, deployed_index=deploy_ann_index
)
```

> ResourceExhausted: 429 The following quotas are exceeded:
> MatchingEngineDeployedIndexNodes

i have list endpoint deployed that was done in previous step.

```
ListIndexEndpointsPager<index_endpoints {
  name: "projects/xxxxxxx/locations/us-central1/indexEndpoints/xxxxxxxx"
  display_name: "index_endpoint_for_demo"
  etag: "AMEw9yPT2hoRkYEEApekieucfedTYyEb5prjgG60WL1pVUfxxxxxxxxxxx"
  create_time {
    seconds: 1645125657
    nanos: 225990000
  }
  update_time {
    seconds: 1645125657
    nanos: 794785000
  }
  network: "projects/xxxxx/global/networks/ucaip-haystack-vpc-network"
}
```

Comment: Under [all quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/quotas) you can find which quota is at 100% and request an increase.

Comment: Already checked that nothing reached above 70%

Answer (score 0):

If an index is using multiple shards, you need to calculate your available quota by dividing it by number of shards used for 1 replica count. For example, if your index is spread across 10 shards and you have quota of 50, at max you can set max_replica_count to 5 (50/10).

You can check how many shards your index uses by going to Metrics Explorer and looking up Matching Engine metrics, see more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/matching-engine/using-matching-engine#monitoring).